# PhoneGap Build integrated with Dreamweaver CS6 is different than CS5.5, how can I change the assets/www folder?

Tags: api, jquery-mobile, cordova, build

I used DW5.5 to build a PhoneGap application before, and it was easy to access all of the files within the app to integrate such things as native API functionallity etc...

But now I am using DWCS6, I cant seem to locate the whole app folder structure. All it does is compiles the app to an .apk file (android) and you download it. Am I missing something here?

I am using jQuery mobile and PhoneGap within Dreamweaver CS6 and just tried to test the native API from phonegap, and just cant seem to get it to work. The examples online show the usage of a cordova.js file (which I know is what used to be called phonegap.js or whatever) but the native fiunctionallty doesnt seem to be working.

Any thoughts?? I have been on it all day now so its likely im missing something simple as my head is fuc***.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is Adobe's way of forcing users to pay for their compilation service. AFAIKT, the ability to compile native apps using external programs like Xcode or Eclipse has been removed. I use Dreamweaver 5.5. The issues with mobile app development have been fraught with problems, but, at least, you could find work arounds. I'm hoping that some enterprising CS6 user will find a good workaround for those of us who don't have $$$$ of dollars to buy adobe products, and then more $$ per month to compile the code. Personally, I'm looking for other options. I saved for months to buy cs5.5 and it has never operated as advertised. I found workarounds for Xcode, but nothing for Android. I do like some things about the design/code piece of Dreamweaver, but all in all, I've been disappointed in the product for mobile development.

Keep us posted on your progress.

Thanks.-Rachel

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copying the Site files from Dreamweaver Source Folder to Eclipse www/assets folder and running it on Android Emulator. This worked for me, at least for simple Hello World index.html file, but it is not working for 5 page - HTML site developed in Dreamweaver CS6.

Comment: You need to use the phonegap build service. Just upload a zipped folder with the basics like the index.html and css files, jquery mobile perhaps, and upload to an account on build.phonegap.com. It automatically inserts the correct cordova/phonegap.js files depending on the platform.